# $\Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is from Munkres' Topology:

> Munkres proves $\Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+$ is countably infinite thus:
>
> First define $f:\Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+\rightarrow A$, where $A$ is the subset of $\Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+$ consisting of pairs of $(x,y)$ for which $y\le x$, by the equation $$f(x,y)=(x+y-1,y).$$ Then we construct a function $g: A\rightarrow \Bbb Z_+$ by the formula $$g(x,y)=\frac12 (x-1)x+y.$$ $g \circ f$ is bijection since $f$ and $g$ bijection.

I can't understand how did we guess function $g$. Also, help me visualize it!

Comment: I think that's a really nice question.  I'm picturing A as the usual R^2 plane with dots filled in at integer points (x,y) with x >= y.  One natural way to count the dots is to move left to right, bottom to top, so you count (1,1), then (2,1), then (2,2), then (3,1), ...  The 1/2 * x * (x-1) is counting the number of dots in a triangle, and the + y is counting how far up you've gone.  Does that make any sense??  Unfortunately I don't know how to draw the dots.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Here is a picture to go with my comment]
Here is a picture to go with my comment

Comment: Thank you very much for such an effort. You told in the comment that 1/2 * x * (x-1) is counting the number of dots in a triangle. I cannot figure out in which triangle.  If you can please elaborate ...

Comment: Thanks Silent!  In the picture, (1/2)*x*(x-1) is the number of points in the triangle from the 1 to the 7 to the 10.  These numbers of the form (1/2)*x*(x-1), which are 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ..., where x is an integer that's at least 2, are called "triangular numbers".  They're similar to "square" numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ...

Answer (score 1):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ypd0aathde

I made this graph to demonstrate that $g(a,a)+1=g(a+1,1)$ and that $g(a,b)+1=g(a,b+1)$ for the restrictions above

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and taking me to a cool site!

Answer (score 1):

Another nice way to see the countability of $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+$ is to use basic number theory and note that any number can be uniquely written as the product of an odd number and a power of $2$ (just keep on dividing by 2 till we get an odd number).

This shows that $f(n,m) = (2n-1)\cdot 2^m$ from $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is a bijection. (the unicity follows from a fundamental theorem of number theory, the unicity of the prime factorisation).